# Android Switch Get Text or Transistion Not OnCheckedChanged

Tags: java, android, user-interface, uiswitch

I need to use Androids Switch button control but I need to be able to detect changes when the user is dragging the control not on clicking. So if the user drags from off to on and holds it in the on position I need to detect that. I thought I could just set the onTouchListener and then look at when the switches text changes state (on/off off/on) and then trigger my changes then but I can't. The

```
mySwitch.getText()
```

Does not work for me. It return blank text even though I have the textOn and textOff attributes set. I need to be able to detect the state change when the user is dragging, not on click. The onCheckedChanged listener will not work for me since that triggers only when the user toggles or slides and lifts there finger off of the button. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Basic Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private TextView switchStatus;
    private Switch mySwitch;
    private TextView mySwitchText;
    private String oldState;

 private Handler handler = new Handler();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  switchStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.switchStatus);
  mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

  //set the switch to ON 
  mySwitch.setChecked(false);
  oldState = mySwitch.getText().toString();
  //attach a listener to check for changes in state
  mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
     boolean isChecked) {

    if(isChecked){
     //switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
    }else{
    // switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
    }

   }
  });

  mySwitch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if(oldState.equals("OFF") && mySwitch.getText().equals("ON")) {
                switchStatus.setText("Off to On");
                oldState = "ON";
            }
            if(oldState.equals("ON") && mySwitch.getText().equals("OFF")) {
                switchStatus.setText("On to Off");
                oldState = "OFF";
            }
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Old State: " + oldState + " my Switch: " + mySwitch.getText().toString());
        return false;
    }
});

  mySwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mySwitch.isChecked()) {
            mySwitch.setChecked(false);
        }
    }   
  }); 

  //check the current state before we display the screen
  if(mySwitch.isChecked()){
   switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
  }
  else {
   switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
  }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  return true;
 }

}
```

Comment: Let us see some code ..

Comment: This can be removed, I went an entirely different route.

Answer (score 0):

Switch is a distant descendant of textview. Therefore you'd have to do this to make it work.

```
oldState = (TextView)mySwitch.getText().toString();
```

However, Switch has a textOn and textOff that works for this purpose.